# computing the larger of two integers in arm assembly

Tags: assembly, arm

So I am attempting to write a piece of ARM assembly for my Raspberry Pi, and I am having it prompt for two integers, a and b, and then comparing them to see which one is larger, and then printing which number is larger.

I am able to read in the two integers, but it always prints out that the second integer 'b' is the largest, and then sometimes gives me a segmentation fault. I have used gbd to see why i am reaching he segfault, but I have been unable to decipher what it means.

gdb says this

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x400b5c38 in strchrnul () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6

and my code is this

```
.section        .rodata
promptA:
        .ascii  "a: \000"
promptB:
        .ascii  "b: \000"
readA:
        .ascii "%d\000"
readB:
        .ascii "%d\000"
printLargest:
        .ascii  "largest=%d\n\000"

.section        .data
        .align 2

        .comm   a,4,4
        .comm   b,4,4

        .text

addra:  .word a
addrb:  .word b
addrPromptA:    .word promptA
addrPromptB:    .word promptB
addrReadA:      .word readA
addrReadB:      .word readB
addrPrintLargest:       .word printLargest



main:
        stmfd sp!, {fp, lr}

        ldr     r0, addrPromptA
        bl      printf

        ldr     r0, addrReadA
        ldr     r1, addra
        bl      scanf                              

        ldr     r0, addrPromptB
        bl      printf

        ldr     r0, addrReadB
        ldr     r1, addrb
        bl      scanf

        ldr     r0,addra
        ldr     r0, [r0]
        ldr     r1, addrb
        ldr     r1, [r1]

        cmp     r1, r0
        mov     r0, r1
        bgt     bgreater
        blt     agreater
agreater:
        ldr     r0, addrPrintLargest
        bl      printf
bgreater:
       ldr     r1, addrPrintLargest
       bl printf

       ldmfd      sp!, {fp, pc}
```

Thank you

Comment: I wonder which university this is, quite a few similar questions recently.

Comment: @JamesGreenhalgh The code structure looks very close to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19391669/arm-assembly-getting-a-string-from-stdin).  Perhaps they are being taught by the same prof who doesn't understand `ldr r0,=myBuffer` and insists on redundant `\000` for a terminator.  Zero is zero in any base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you're putting `B` in `r0` regardless of the result of the `cmp`:

```
cmp     r1, r0
mov     r0, r1
```

Here you print `B` (since it's also in `r1`):

```
agreater:
    ldr     r0, addrPrintLargest
    bl      printf
```

Then you proceed with executing this code as well, since there's no branch after the above `bl`:

```
bgreater:
   ldr     r1, addrPrintLargest
   bl printf
```

This might be what's causing the segfault, depending on what `r0` happened to contain.

---

I'd suggest doing something like this:

```
    ldr     r0,addra
    ldr     r0, [r0]
    ldr     r1, addrb
    ldr     r1, [r1]

    cmp     r0, r1  
    movgt   r1, r0   @ if (r0 > r1) r1 = r0
    ldr     r0, addrPrintLargest
    bl      printf
```

Comment: thanks! I solved my problem. I was making it more complicated that it should have been